# How to combine pack and grid in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem that has been already discussed on stackoverflow many time, but I still do not understand, how can I adjust my code to work properly.
Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()


def raise_bilance():

    labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Bilance today")
    labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

    left = tk.Label(labelframe, text="Profit $1.000.000")
    left.pack()


f1 = tk.Frame(root)


f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

tk.Button(
    f1, text="Click on me", command=lambda: raise_bilance()
).pack()
tk.Label(f1, text="Click").pack()


raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

I got this error:

> `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid`

How can I modify my code to work properly, please? I tried to replace `pack()` with `grid()` and vice versa, but it did not help me.

Comment: You cannot mix ```grid``` and ```pack```. Either stick to ```grid``` or ```pack```.

Comment: Use `.grid(...)` on `labelframe` instead of `.pack(...)`. It should fix the problem.